# Issues with getting row from my database and turning it into string laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

this is my code

```
public function GetUsersWhoNeedPayments()
{

    $All_DB_Email_Info = DB::table('users')->pluck('email');
    foreach($All_DB_Email_Info as $ADEI){

         $DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom = Auth::user()->where([
        ['paired_with', '=', $ADEI]
    ])->get();

    var_dump($DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom->name);
    }
}
```

So I created the variable $All_DB_Email_Info which selects the email column. my goal is to get the email saved in my DB...every user is paired to make payment to other users...so i am paired to make payment to johndoe@example.com,,i want the check the db for johndoe@example.com and then check for he's ->name, phonenumber->, ->age, etc..but when i reload my page the page says 'Exception in Colection.php line 1498: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.' Please help me out

Comment: instead of $DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom = Auth::user()->where([
        ['paired_with', '=', $ADEI]
    ])->get(); try $DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom = Auth::user()->where([
        ['paired_with', '=', $ADEI]
    ])->first();

Comment: it says 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: Because there is no record for your query, try this condition if($DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom) { var_dump($DisplayUserToReceivePaymentFrom->name); } else { echo 'No record found'; }